# How to break word in pdf header, PDF generated using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

How to break words in Headers in PDF file, while generating PDF using jsPDF(i.e. I want to break the headers like "Hello World" into two lines)  and how to set font size in jsPDF.

I have tried with `pdf.setFontSize(12);` , but it does not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**code:**

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a3')   
    , source = $('#TableId')[0] 
    , specialElementHandlers = {

    }

    , margins = {  top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 30, width: 922 };


    pdf.fromHTML(
        source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        , margins.left // x coord
        , margins.top // y coord
        , {
            'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
            , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
        function (dispose) {          
          pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        },
        margins
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split hello and world on two different lines, add a newline `\n` between `hello` and `world`: `"hello\nworld"`

Example:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.setFontSize(12);
pdf.text(10, 10, "Hello\nWorld");
```

Or add two text fields:

```
doc.text(10, 10, "Hello");
doc.text(10, 25, "World");
```

**ps. It would even more help if you could post all your code.**

Comment: I have updated my code. I have tried as you have suggested still it is NOT working. Help me

Answer (score 0):

If You use FromHtml and your Text spent more than one Page, so you can add after the Text :
  `<!-- ADD_PAGE -->`

But you should use the Jspdf from Mrrio libary

**Link** :  [Download the Jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: If you're going to promote a third-party library, you should explain why it's relevant to your answer. This looks like spam in its current state.